# BizTalk Varying Length Flat File using Single Schema for Transform

Tags: biztalk, flat-file, biztalk-mapper

I have a pipe delimited .txt Flat File that I'm using to do bulk insert to SQL.  Everything works well for straight one to one.  However, the Flat File now contains 2 new fields that can repeat an unknown number of times.

Is there a way to create a single flat file schema where I can have an unbounded child within the main unbounded child?  I think the place I'm getting tripped up is how to make the ChildRoot listed below just a "group heading" like Root is where ChildRoot doesn't correspond to a location in the flat file.  How do I insert something like that?

```
Schema:
-Roots
--Root (unbounded)
---ChildID
---ChildName
```

Roots gets a direct link to my sql stored procedure to do a bulk insert on as many "Root" rows that come in.

Now I have:

```
Schema:
-Roots
--Root (unbounded)
---Child
---ChildName
---ChildRoot (unbounded)
----ChildRootID
----ChildRootName
```

**EDIT
I should also add that ChildRootID & ChildRootName can repeat an indefinite number of times until the row delimiter (carriage return) is found

Comment: Okay.  It turns out just writing this question out helped me work through the answer.

All I did was make a new child record with all the same settings (ie delimiter value, infix, etc) as Root, then I made its max occurs unbounded and min occurs 0.  Then placed each of the records "ChildRootID" and "ChildRootName" under ChildRoot (indented).  Voila!

Knew it was too easy.